# COUNTIF From multiple Columns

Tags: regex, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

So I have a column I need to count it has two words in it Completed, and Scheduled. What I'm trying to do is count these if it matches a name from the A column.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(MONTH(TEST!B:B),MONTH(TODAY()),TEST!A:A,"Jack"))
```

I wrote the above function, and it does count everything for the current date with the name Jack in it. I would like it to count how many Completed / Scheduled jack did.

Something like this...

[image: Screenshot of what I'm trying to do]

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
=sumproduct(TEST!A:A="Jack", month(TEST!B:B)=month(today()), regexmatch(TEST!D:D, "Scheduled|Completed"))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like it to count how many **Completed / Scheduled** Jack did.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 COUNTIFS(TEST!B:B, G7, MONTH(TEST!C:C), MONTH(TODAY()), TEST!E:E, "completed")&" / "&
 COUNTIFS(TEST!B:B, G7, MONTH(TEST!C:C), MONTH(TODAY()), TEST!E:E, "scheduled"))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

`=QUERY({B2:B,C2:C,E2:E},
"select Col3, count(Col2) 
 where month(Col2)+1 = " & month(now()) & " and Col1 = 'Jack' 
 group by Col3")`

[image]